# Handling database table entries with backslashes?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, backslash

We're running into a weird edge case where we are trying to store a json blob in a table in our database, and that blob needs to be able to contain the `\` character. So a user were to enter in `\test` it needs to come back as exactly that, but instead its coming back as a tab followed by "est"

As far as I can tell, whats happening is that when a user enters and submits `"\test"` it gets evaluated into "\ \test" (remove the space, cant put two backslashes in here and have it display right?) by the client and then entered into the table. I can verify that in the SQL that gets called against the table there are two backslashes. When I look at it in the table after this step its back to `"\test"`. When the client loads it up again it gets evaluated into a tab followed by an "est".

We are under the impression that the second backslash is necessary so that the first backslash will get escaped and not evaluated but maybe that is what is causing issues? I sort of assume when the query runs one of the backslashes gets escaped anyway but I'm not really sure what to do about that. Is there something with out our database is handling backslashes that we need to be looking out for? Is there a way to handle this that we haven't considered?

It's a Postgres database if that's helpful. I'd say I'm beginner to intermediate on this sort of thing, I'm looking through documentation but if anyone can even point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

Postgres version as far as i can tell through Amazon Aws is 9.3

EDIT
I think ive tracked this issue down to a line in our php backend that I don't really understand. I'm looking at the documentation for that now and will mark this as answered since I've verified that its not an issue with SQL.

Comment: A backslash as - by default - no special meaning in SQL. This might be caused by whatever code is processing those values (and sending them to the database). See here for an online example: http://rextester.com/QLLYG57275

Comment: It would be interesting to know the exact SQL statement and what PostgreSQL version that is.

Comment: Am I misinterpreting this postgres documentation? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

It seems to imply in 4.1.2.2 that C-like escapes are accepted using the \ character

Comment: But only for "escaped" (non-standard) strings that start with `E'` e.g. `E'\t'`, not regular strings like `'\t'` - but that is something your application code would do (and please don't use the manual for outdated and unsupported versions)

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote A backslash as - by default - no special meaning in SQL. This might be caused by whatever code is processing those values (and sending them to the database). See here for an online example: rextester.com/QLLYG57275 – a_horse_with_no_name

I'm accepting this as the answer as I've verified that the issue is with out backend code constructing the SQL, and not how the SQL is being handled on the database end.